# Flask Showing Shape of Uploaded CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have **app.py** file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        return render_template('upload.html', shape=df.shape)
    return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and **upload.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
Shape is: {{ shape }}
</body>
</html>
```

and **dummy.csv** file:

```
id,name,surname
1,John,Doe
2,Jane,Doe
```

I would like to show shape of the data when I upload the csv file. I cannot get the shape of the data with my implementation. I appreciate any hints/ helps.

Comment: Is this csv file located locally on your machine?

Comment: Yes, dummy.csv is located in my local machine.

Comment: The code that you have here is working fine on my side. I am getting Shape: (2,3) for this same csv file

Comment: I run firstly app.py via bash/command line. Then open .html file with browser. Did you also do this ? I do not know why it does not work my side

Comment: Yes, here is what I did. replicated your code on my side using Visual studio code. Then, I ran app.py using command line. It will give me the address of my local host and where it is running. I go to that address. For me it was http://my-local-address:5000. Now, since your route is /upload. you have to go to this route: http://my-local-address:5000/upload. There you can upload and see your shape.

Comment: When I go to the adress, I get 404 Not Found Error: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. For this route, I get Jinja2 template not found error.

Comment: What address did you get when you ran your app.py? You did not use the address that I commented above, did you? You used your own local host address right?

Comment: Yes I used my local host address which is shown in the bash

Comment: Thank a lot. Please post your answer so that I can upvote it. In comment, there is no upvote option.

Comment: I want to upvote, but my reputation is not enough :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Create a templates folder and put your upload.html file inside the templates folder. Since, you do not have it inside the templates folder, flask is returning you jinga2 template not found error.

Just like all the images need to be inside static folder, all the html templates need to be inside the templates folder inorder for your application to work.

Hope this helps!