# How to show size of dataset in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have such a dataset. User can choose certain time interval via slider to adjust time interval in minutes. I would like display the size of dataset at the beginning of web page. **If user changes the time interval, the size of dataset should change dynamically as well as showing how many datapoints are removed dynamically**.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output,dash_table

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00',freq='20min'),
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION']==1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2,3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df.DATE_TIME.diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df['TIMEINTERVAL'].fillna(0)



def to_day_period(s):
    bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
    labels = ['Nighttime', 'Daytime', 'Daytime', 'Nighttime', 'Nighttime']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(s),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = to_day_period(df['TIME'])
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Interactive Scatter Plot'),
    html.P("Select ID:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(df.ID.unique(), id='pandas-dropdown-1'),  # for choosing ID,
    html.P("Filter by time interval during nighttime (18:00-6:00):"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='range-slider-night',
        min=0, max=600, step=10,
        marks={0: '0', 50: '50', 100: '100', 150: '150', 200: '200', 250: '250', 300: '300', 350: '350', 400: '400',
               450: '450', 500: '500', 550: '550', 600: '600'},
        value=[0, 600]
    ),
    html.P("Filter by time interval during daytime (6:00-18:00):"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='range-slider-morning',
        min=0, max=600, step=10,
        marks={0: '0', 50: '50', 100: '100', 150: '150', 200: '200', 250: '250', 300: '300', 350: '350', 400: '400',
               450: '450', 500: '500', 550: '550', 600: '600'},
        value=[0, 600]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="scatter-plot", style={'width': '130vh', 'height': '80vh'}),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    Output("scatter-plot", "figure"),
    Input("pandas-dropdown-1", "value"),
    Input("range-slider-night", "value"),
    Input("range-slider-morning", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True)

def update_lineplot(value, slider_range_night, slider_range_morning):
    low_night, high_night = slider_range_night
    low_morning, high_morning = slider_range_morning
    df_night = df.query("ID == @value & TIME_OF_DAY == 'Night' & TIMEINTERVAL >= @low_night & TIMEINTERVAL < @high_night").copy()
    df_morning = df.query("ID == @value & TIME_OF_DAY == 'Morning' & TIMEINTERVAL >= @low_morning & TIMEINTERVAL < @high_morning").copy()
    df1 = pd.concat([df_night, df_morning], axis=0).sort_values(['DATE_TIME'])

    if df1.shape[0] != 0:
        fig = px.line(df1, x="DATE_TIME", y=["VALUE1", "VALUE2"],
                         facet_col='INSPECTION',
                         facet_col_wrap=2,
                         symbol='MODE',hover_data=['TIMEINTERVAL'],
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09)

        fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)

        return fig
    else:
        return no_update

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I know that I can do such a task in Flask [like in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74289930/flask-showing-shape-of-uploaded-csv-file). But how can I adapt this solution in Dash?

Comment: You want to display the size of the selected points and the remaining unselected points? the sum of selected and unselected points = the total size of the dataset, right?

Comment: Another question, which dataset did you mean because you have df1 and df in your code?

Comment: @Hamzah, yes I would liek to display size of selected points and remaining unselected points separately. Besides, this size display should be both for daytime and nighttime separately. I meant df actually. I used df1 to use filtered code.

Comment: For instance, if the user selects 1 from the dropdown the size of df after this selection and  the size of the remaining entries in df which belong to 2. Then another display will be for points of nighttime and another display will be daytime, right?

Comment: @Hamzah I thought that user chooses a certain range from slider. Then, under those sliders, there will be html output so that user can see how many datapoints are selected and how many unselected for each daytime and nighttime dynamically. The html output should change accordingly with range of slider. Now I correct myself, df1 should be used actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try it out and tell me if that what you are trying to do:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output,dash_table, no_update

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00',freq='20min'),
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION']==1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2,3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df.DATE_TIME.diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df['TIMEINTERVAL'].fillna(0)



def to_day_period(s):
    bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
    labels = ['Nighttime', 'Daytime', 'Daytime', 'Nighttime', 'Nighttime']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(s),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = to_day_period(df['TIME'])
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Interactive Scatter Plot'),
    html.Div('Size of dataset = '+str(len(df)),id='size',style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap'}),
    html.P("Select ID:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(df.ID.unique(), id='pandas-dropdown-1'),  # for choosing ID,
    html.P("Filter by time interval during nighttime (18:00-6:00):"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='range-slider-night',
        min=0, max=600, step=10,
        marks={0: '0', 50: '50', 100: '100', 150: '150', 200: '200', 250: '250', 300: '300', 350: '350', 400: '400',
               450: '450', 500: '500', 550: '550', 600: '600'},
        value=[0, 600]
    ),
    html.P("Filter by time interval during daytime (6:00-18:00):"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='range-slider-morning',
        min=0, max=600, step=10,
        marks={0: '0', 50: '50', 100: '100', 150: '150', 200: '200', 250: '250', 300: '300', 350: '350', 400: '400',
               450: '450', 500: '500', 550: '550', 600: '600'},
        value=[0, 600]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="scatter-plot", style={'width': '130vh', 'height': '80vh'}),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
])


@app.callback(
    Output("scatter-plot", "figure"),
    Output("size", "children"),
    Input("pandas-dropdown-1", "value"),
    Input("range-slider-night", "value"),
    Input("range-slider-morning", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True)

def update_lineplot(value, slider_range_night, slider_range_morning):
    low_night, high_night = slider_range_night
    low_morning, high_morning = slider_range_morning
    df_night = df.query("(ID == @value) & (TIME_OF_DAY == 'Nighttime') & (TIMEINTERVAL >= @low_night) & (TIMEINTERVAL < @high_night)").copy()
    df_morning = df.query("(ID == @value) & (TIME_OF_DAY == 'Daytime') & (TIMEINTERVAL >= @low_morning) & (TIMEINTERVAL < @high_morning)").copy()
    df1 = pd.concat([df_night, df_morning], axis=0).sort_values(['DATE_TIME'])
    
    
    text = f"The size of dataset = {len(df)} \n Selected points = {len(df1)}, unselected points = {len(df) - len(df1)}, \n df_night = {len(df_night)}, df_morning = {len(df_morning)}"
    
    if df1.shape[0] != 0:
        fig = px.line(df1, x="DATE_TIME", y=["VALUE1", "VALUE2"],
                         facet_col='INSPECTION',
                         facet_col_wrap=2,
                         symbol='MODE',hover_data=['TIMEINTERVAL'],
                         facet_row_spacing=0.1,
                         facet_col_spacing=0.09)

        fig.update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)

        return fig,text
    else:
        return no_update
    

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output:**

[image]

You will find here how I calculate the sizes ;

```
text = f"The size of dataset = {len(df)} \n Selected points = {len(df1)}, unselected points = {len(df) - len(df1)}, \n df_night = {len(df_night)}, df_morning = {len(df_morning)}"
```